# add selectbox dynamically on hyperlink click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically add `<select>` elements, but when I click 'add more fields', no `<select>` element is added. Is this because I use a hyperlink instead of a button? (Button does not work either.)

What's going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields = 5; //maximum select boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><select name="res_id[]"><option value="">select resort</option><option value="1664">Aalen</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <a href="#" class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</a>
</div>
```

Comment: An error is thrown: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: yes I did add the Jquery lib

Comment: @mark edited the snippet to include jQuery.  It appears to work as is.

Comment: it appears to be one of the resorts name in the selectbox (I left out several here for a compact code section). How can I prevent the option sequence being interupted by exotic resort names?

Comment: Please update your code to include one of the names in question (or something similar that helps demonstrate the issue). That way we can reproduce the problem and investigate.

Comment: Jöhstadt is the name which causes the problem

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/sp91rmL7/). Can you [reproduce it here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: no, the strange thing is I can't. It must be something else then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the variables at the top of your code to hold the JQuery objects. You then use the JQuery constructor again around the objects you created (`$(add_button)`). You should just be using `add_button` without the wrapping constructor, as I'm not sure the way you're doing it would work. Also, I like to use `$(function(){})`, as it ensures the DOM has loaded.

```js
$(function() {

  var max_fields = 5; //maximum select boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1;
  add_button.click(function(e) { //on add button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      wrapper.append('<div><select name="res_id[]"><option value="">select resort</option><option value="1664">Aalen</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <a href="#" class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</a>
</div>
```